# Cannot invoke 'presentViewController' Swift

Tags: swift, viewcontroller

I am trying to display a NSViewController as i click a button in an other NSViewController. My NSViewControllers are designed with xib.
Ive looked around a bit and have come up with

```
class TimesVC: NSViewController{
...
    @IBAction func editButton(sender: AnyObject) {
         let vc:EditMenuVC = EditMenuVC()
         self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

but that last line has the error:

"Cannot invoke 'presentViewController' with an argurment list of type (EditMenuVC, animated:Bool, completion:nil)"

The other ViewController I am trying to open is called "EditMenuVC" and also uses a xib.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you're confusing the iOS UIViewController, where there's a function that matches that signature:

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/presentViewController:animated:completion:

versus the MacOS X NSViewController, whose closest matches are as follows:

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSViewController/presentViewController:animator:

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSViewController/transitionFromViewController:toViewController:options:completionHandler:

Comment: would have been helpful, if you would have presented the needed function tho